# Convert date with known timezone to UTC date

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Date and Time Conversion has always been my weak link. I have the following values in string format:

1. String date="2015-08-21 03:15" and timezone for this date is
2. String timeZone="GMT+05:30";

Now I need to covert this date, for which I already know the timezone, to UTC date.

Comment: Can you use the Java 8 date/time API?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I am using Java8 only

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See correct [Answer by Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115584/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given time in "GMT+05:30" timezone next code will convert it to UTC timezone:

```
String strDate = "2015-08-21 03:15";
String timeZone="GMT+05:30";
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmz";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date dateStr = formatter.parse(strDate+timeZone);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String formattedDate = formatter.format(dateStr);
System.out.println("UTC datetime is: "+formattedDate);
```

Comment: your code gives an output as 2015-08-20 22:15 Z According to this website it should be 21- Aug 9:45 pm  http://www.worldtimeserver.com/convert_time_in_UTC.aspx?y=2015&mo=8&d=20&h=21&mn=45

Comment: @HiteshBhutani I've slightly updated the code. Correct answer is 20-Aug 21:45 UTC. And yes, it should be 20th of August, not 21, because UTC is 'behind' GMT+5:30

Comment: Perfect. And yes the correct answer is 20th Aug. I realized after I posted the comment that it was incorrect but forgot to update. Thanks for the rescue. I will mark the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

> Approach 1: Using Java Date:

```
//Your input date string
String date="2015-08-21 03:15";

// date format your string
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

//Create SimpleDateFormat instance
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

// Convert Local Time to UTC 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

//parse your input date string to UTC date
Date gmtTime = new Date(sdf.parse(date));
```

> Approach 2: Using Joda time (recommended)

```
String dateString = "2015-08-21 03:15:00+5:30";

String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ";

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);

DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateString);

System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Comment: In your code i do not see you have used the timezone GMT+05:30. What you have written will pickup the default timezone of the server and will convert it UTC time. Lets say the your code runs on a server which is in MST timezone. It will consider the date 2015-08-21 03:15 as MST date and convert it to UTC date. Which is what i don't want. I already know this date is in GMT+05:30 timezone ie IST and need to convert that to UTC time.

Comment: @HiteshBhutani .. I updated the answer, you need Joda time for handling the +5:30 case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want a Java-8-solution:

```
String input = "2015-08-21 03:15";
String offsetInfo = "GMT+05:30";

LocalDateTime ldt = 
  LocalDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm"));
ZoneOffset offset = 
  ZoneOffset.of(offsetInfo.substring(3)); // GMT-prefix needs to be filtered out

LocalDateTime result = 
  ldt.atOffset(offset).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
System.out.print(result); // output: 2015-08-20T21:45
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
try {
    //Here you say to java the initial timezone. This is the secret
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    date = sdf.parse(review);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

//Here you set to your timezone
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: What is `review`? As far as I can see, this is trying to convert a UTC Date to a local Date (which is not what the OP was asking for).

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` in java represents the number of milliseconds since 1970. This number alone has no specific time zone. This means if you create a Date with `new Date()` you get the current milliseconds since 1970 and if you call toString on it this value gets represented in your current locale timezone. The actual time this number represents is time zone specific. This is the reason why you can set a `TimeZone` on `Calendar` and Format classes.

To instantiate a calendar with a specific TimeZone you can do this:

```
public static Calendar getUtcCalendar() {
   GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

So to convert a `Date` to a specific time in UTC TimeZone:

```
Calendar calendar = getUtcCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);
return calendar;
```